# How can I give Ajax data (list) to mustache?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, mustache

I want to put the user object I received as Ajax into {{#user}} in mustache and render it on the screen.

```
    <table class="table table-horizontal table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-strong">
    <tr>
        <th>user number</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    {{#users}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{id}}</td>

        </tr>
    {{/users}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is conroller

```
    @PostMapping("/api/v1/eduPosts/registerAdminToUser")
public List<User> registerAdminToUser(@RequestBody UserRegisterRequestDto userRegisterRequestDto){

    List<User> users=userService.registerAdminToUser(userRegisterRequestDto);
    System.out.println(users);
    return users;
}
```

this is `index.js`

```
    update : function () {
    var data = {
        adminId: $('#adminId').val(),
        userId: $('#userId').val()
    };

    //var id = $('#id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/v1/eduPosts/registerAdminToUser',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(idx, val) {
        alert(idx + " " + val.id);
        console.log(idx + " " + val.id)
    });
       alert(JSON.stringify(data))
    }).fail(function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Should I change the js file? Or do I have to change the mustache template?
If I print out the user object in the `index.js` file, the data is being rendered properly.

Thanks!